# AngularJs Datetimepicker

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I've got this problem for quit some time now:

I'm using the AngularJs datetimepicker https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker. I've implemented it like this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label >Einddatum: {{ employeeCtrl.employee.EndDate }}</label>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle my-toggle-select" id="enddate" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="">
            <div class="input-append"><input type="text" class="input-large" data-ng-model="employeeCtrl.employee.EndDate"><span class="add-on"><i
                    class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
            <datetimepicker data-ng-model="employeeCtrl.employee.EndDate" data-datetimepicker-config="{ minView: 'day' }"></datetimepicker>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when the value is stored it saves the previous day. So if I select June 2 it puts June 1 in the database?

When I show the selected date like this:

```
<label >Einddatum: {{ employeeCtrl.employee.EndDate }}</label>
```

The date is correct! What could be wrong here? I need the timzone Amsterdam!

Comment: It is possible there is nothing wrong. Is the date stored in the database may be a different time zone than the date displayed in the UI. This is not necessarily a problem. Imagine you store the dates in the data base as UTC and display the dates to the user in their local time zone - both dates represent the same moment in time, just different geographic locations.